# HTML Agility Pack - Filter Href Value Results

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm working on a web scraper. The following text shows the results of the code given at the end of this question, which gets the values of all hrefs from a page.

I only want to get values that contain `docid=`

> index.php?pageid=a45475a11ec72b843d74959b60fd7bd64556e8988583f
>
> #
>
> summary_of_documents.php
>
> index.php?pageid=a45475a11ec72b843d74959b60fd7bd64579b861c1d7b
>
> #
>
> index.php?pageid=a45475a11ec72b843d74959b60fd7bd64579e0509c7f0&apform=judiciary
>
> decisions.php?doctype=Decisions / Signed
>   Resolutions&docid=1263778435388003271#sam
>
> decisions.php?doctype=Decisions / Signed
>   Resolutions&docid=12637789021669321156#sam
>
> ?doctype=Decisions / Signed Resolutions&year=1986&month=January#head
>
> ?doctype=Decisions / Signed Resolutions&year=1986&month=February#head

Here's the code:

```
        string url = urlTextBox.Text;
        string sourceCode = Extractor.getSourceCode(url);

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(sourceCode);
        List<string> links = new List<string>();

        if (links != null)
        {
            foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode nd in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
            {
                links.Add(nd.Attributes["href"].Value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Links Found");
        }

        if (links != null)
        {
            foreach (string str in links)
            {
                richTextBox9.Text += str + "\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Link Values Found");
        }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I made a few edits here. Please double check :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just replace this:

```
links.Add(nd.Attributes["href"].Value);
```

with this:

```
if (nd.Attributes["href"].Value.Contains("docid="))
    links.Add(nd.Attributes["href"].Value);
```